# Method to mirror/flip transform image files in React Native?

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Is there a way to transform image files in React Native, such that the result is an image flipped along the vertical axis (mirrored image)?

I'm not looking for a library that simply displays mirrored/flipped components -- many of these exist. Instead, I need to actually transform the image file (which will be uploaded to an S3 bucket).

Basically I'm looking for a solution that's similar to what `react-native-image-resizer` does for resizing images: original image file as input, mirrored/flipped image file as output.